# I need a yes no field but the table doesn't have one .The table is read only to me

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

My task at work is to produce , without unnecessary  effort, an “approved  by supervisor “  set of records  to print off  via a report    .This is done weekly  from  records identified using a  simply select query run aon a linked table over which I have no control,  just read only access.

Problem 1)I am Working from a regularly updated  source table which is on the intranet . It is a table  I cannot  edit  in any way  . Nor can  I get anyone else to edit  it.
 This table does not  currently have a Yes /No field I can only link to the table
Please refer to this table in answers as    “tblsource”

MY WorkaRound  so far is :-
Current  working prototype  idea  is  to achieved Approval  via a  Yes/No   tick box  field  facility  added in. (Tick box  is the speediest  way to work  through the selected records  and give “approved  by supervisor “  (that’s me ) approval to .   Selecting  records via a combo box  would  far to slow )
 I have  currently successfully done this with a make table query  and then manually adding the yes/No Field   to the “tblmade”  but  this leads to a problem 2) ..

Problem 2)  maintaining  the “approved “status  of records  until the next time the list is accessed  ,when records may or may not still exist in  the source  table . The problems in my current work around is that .. 
Using a make table query  necessarily  seems to means  fresh start every time ie all records erased then re populated  and so replicating lot of work in approving existing  records  again

My additional thought for overcoming Problem 2) are -Would it be possible to create some kind of query against tblsource  that would populate a table where my checked boxes remain intact  against unique records ie the primary key of the source table   I have research Dlookup but cannot yet see a way of achieving this 
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------
I will happily elaborate on the work I have to do and the  nature of the  problems  I am encountering

Some Further Info
The primary index in tblsource  is a txt field  with unique serial numbers  /letters
The other 3 fields from tbsource I use  are all txt fields

Problem 1) the source tbl does not have  a  yes/ no field  and the source table  is only available as linked to and cannot be modified  ie Read only  privileges

Problem 2) The tblsource is updated/ changed daily  with around 5-8 % deletions and or 
additions 
This is not a large data set  there are only 1100-1200 records in tblsource and after my simple select query i only have to scan 150 -200 to approve or not

Please note from my profile ,my MS Access skill   levels are  beginner to moderate I can build a macro but raw VBA  is still a way off    but I can  cut and paste  pretty good if you point to where in the properties  list to put it   eg  Data - “onUpdate “ etc

Comment: How do you arrive at the conclusion of saying yes, approved, or no, not approved? Is it from data within your table or some outside knowledge?

Comment: THANKS Brad.. HI the approval is from outside the data set in the field of real world time space intuitive knowledge particularly of human state of mind and  current dispositions.Thanks again Brad for raising this point

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy.

Add a new table `tblForApproval` which contains an ID field (this will be the foreign key to your `tblSource` table - therefore define the appropriate relationship in the lookup tab), and an approval field (yes/no).

[image: Approval table]

Then create a new form and define its data source in a way that it left-joins your `tblSource` with `tblForApproval`.

[image: Form data source]

Then add some text fields and check boxes to your form and bind these to the return values of your query (see screenshot - Property Sheet - Data - Control Source [field "Approved" has been linked to the table column "Approved"). Don't forget the checkbox for approval and the relevant Save and Next Record buttons.

[image: Form]

This is more or less it. Now you can navigate through your record sets. If you haven't given approval yet, the left join will initially deliver an empty value, but Access will automatically add a record in the approval table once you save the record.

This method will also survive updates to the source table - the approvals are saved separately.

*By the way: this actually does not require any VBA unless you want to do something like "auto-save on clicking approve".*

Comment: I was thinking this exact same method.  The only thing I'd suggest is adding a relationship to the tables and making it Cascading, so that if the tblSourceID gets deleted (the OP says sometimes there are deletes in the source data), the corresponding record in tblForApproval gets deleted too.  This way there aren't any orphaned records.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Out of interest: Is cascading delete possible even if the table is only linked, e.g. on a SQL server?

Comment: Good question.  I would think so, but the user would need Read/Write rights.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to run a make-table query to grab a local copy of the linked table, then add an [Approved] Yes/No field to your local copy. That could be accomplished in VBA with code like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function GetDataForApproval()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, fld As DAO.Field
    Const LocalTableName = "tblForApproval"  ' or whatever name you like

    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, LocalTableName  ' delete old copy
    ' run make-table query
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("", _
            "SELECT * " & _
            "INTO [" & LocalTableName & "] " & _
            "FROM tblsource")
    qdf.Execute
    Set qdf = Nothing
    ' now add [Approved] Yes/No field
    Set fld = New DAO.Field
    fld.Name = "Approved"
    fld.Type = dbBoolean
    cdb.TableDefs(LocalTableName).Fields.Append fld
    fld.Properties.Append fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", dbInteger, acCheckBox)
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi THANKS FOR THESE REPLIES  
PLEASE ACCEPT MY APOLOGIES FOR DELAY IN REPLYING I HAVE BEEN AWAY WATCHING leTour de France in Yorkshire 
I AM GOING TO test out both these solution in real time this week 
expect another post on Sunday or Monday
 Thanks again